# Windows Phone 8 Background Task with notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an app that checks the results of matches in real time.

I want to be able to poll the server every minute to see if there has been any updates on the match. Is this possible, or do my users need to keep the app open to get live results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not be allowed to do any form of real-time polling in a background task on Windows Phone.

However, if you keep your application open in the foreground, you can do all the polling you like.

Answer (score 4):

Primarily you should consider [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

[Background mode for location services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the alternative. Maybe it can work during a game. It does drain battery thou.

Answer (score 4):

I know whatsapp uses a hack to do this, using the audio sdk. You could try to see if that works for you. Here is an example of the audio sdk http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx