# Windows phone 8 push notifications

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

I have question about push notifications in Windows phone 8.
As i understand, there are three types of push notification:

1. Toast Notification.
2. Tile Notification.
3. Raw Notification.

So, in my opinion:

*if the app is running, and opened in foreground:*

1. Toast will be not shown, but i can handle it`s event and do something.
2. Tile will be updated automaticaly
3. Raw Notification must be handled by me. (**Question one: can i do it without background task?**)

*if the app is running now, but suspended:*

1. Toast will be shown as it came, without any event handling in my app, only "BindToToast()"
2. Tile Will be updated, without any event handling, only "BindToTile()"
3. Raw notification must be handled by background Task.

*if the app is not open:*

1. Toast will be shown automaticaly, if in previous launch "BindToToast()" was called.
2. Tile will update automaticaly, if in previous launch "BindToTile()" was called,
3. **Question 2: what about raw notification? how to handle it here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the situation is as follows:

- Toast notification is shown only when the app is not running, but can be intercepted when it is
- Tile notification always updates the tile regardless of application running
- Raw notification can only be processed by the application when running.

Toast/raw notifications cannot normally be handled by a background task in Windows Phone 8.0. But there maybe a hack to get around this. See [Windows Phone 8 notifications and background tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084955/windows-phone-8-notifications-and-background-tasks) and [Windows Phone 8 Background Task with notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864633/windows-phone-8-background-task-with-notifications)

In Windows phone 8.1 it is quite possible to create a background task that is invoked when a notification is received, so the notification can be processed by the background task.